# Embeddings of the maximal domain for the Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain and $n \geq 2$. Consider the subspace of $L^2$-functions whose distributional Laplacian is also an $L^2$-function:

$$D = \left\{ f \in L^2(\Omega): \ \Delta f  \in L^2(\Omega)\right\}$$

This space is known as the domain of the maximal operator associated with the Laplacian on $L^2$. I am wondering whether there are any embedding results for the space $D$ into spaces with higher order integrability, e.g. $L^p$ for some $p>2$ over $\Omega$ (or some weighted spaces). The elliptic regularity implies that $D \subset H^2_{loc}(\Omega)$. So the question boils down to whether one can control the functions from $D$ as we approach the boundary $\partial \Omega$. I'll appreciate any reference that discusses properties of functions from this space.

Comment: [Sobolev embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#General_Sobolev_inequalities) + elliptic regularity (which allows you to pass from $D$ to $W^{2,2}$)?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think the elliptic regularity should imply that if $f\in D$ then also $f \in H^2_{loc}$ and on compact subsets we can use the Sobolev embedding. I edited my question to ask about embeddings on $\Omega$. For this I'm not sure the elliptic regularity works as we have no boundary condition and $D$ is a larger space than $H^2$

Answer (score 4):

There is no hope to gain summability without using boundary conditions. For example the function $\frac{1}{z \log z}$ is holomorphic, hence harmonic,  and in $L^2$ in the disc (in the complex plane) centered at $\frac 14$ with radius $\frac 14$ but it is not in any $L^p$ for $p>2$.